# Sending JSON information to database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to send the data from a JSON file into a MySQL database using PHP.

I have it working 99% but have run into a small snag I can't figure out.  Here's my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO url_feed(url, results, current_date, networks, identifier) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'sssss', $url, $results, $current_date, $networks, $identifier);

$filename = 'https://www.example.com/random.json';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);   

$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
$url = $row['url'];
$identifier = $row['identifier'];
$current_date = $row['current_date'];
$results = $row['results'];
$networks = $row['networks'];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Here's a copy of a the JSON with 3 objects in it:

```
[
   {
      "url":"http://example1.com",
      "identifier":495755330,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:45",
      "results":3,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":true,"result":"no-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":false,"result":"no-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":true,"result":"no-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":true,"result":"some-result"}
      }
   },
   {
      "url":"http://example2.com",
      "identifier":495755331,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:46",
      "results":0,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":false,"result":"what-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":false,"result":"what-result"}
      }
   },
   {
      "url":"http://example3.com",
      "identifier":495755332,
      "current_date":"2015-12-30 17:05:47",
      "results":1,
      "networks":{
         "FaceBook":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Twitter Inc":{"detected":true,"result":"some-result"},
         "Pinterest.com":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"},
         "Other Sites":{"detected":false,"result":"some-result"}
      }
   }
]
```

Right now if I run the script, it inserts it into the database like this:

```
id | url                 | results   | current_date        | networks | identifier  | status
1  | http://example1.com | 3         | 2015-12-30 17:05:45 | Array    | 495755330   | queued
2  | http://example2.com | 0         | 2015-12-30 17:05:46 | Array    | 495755331   | queued
3  | http://example3.com | 1         | 2015-12-30 17:05:47 | Array    | 495755332   | queued
```

But this is how I **want** it to be entered:

```
id | url                 | results   | current_date        | networks                           | identifier | status
1  | http://example1.com | 3         | 2015-12-30 17:05:45 | FaceBook,Pinterest.com,Other Sites | 495755330  | queued
2  | http://example3.com | 1         | 2015-12-30 17:05:47 | Twitter Inc                        | 495755332  | queued
```

Here's the part I can't figure out:

It's trying to enter as an Array, which obviously isn't working - and it just insert the text "Array" under the `networks` column.  I only want to insert into the database if `detected` is set to `true`.  If it is not, I don't want that social network listed in the database.

If none of the social networks are set to `true` for an object, I don't want that object entered at all.  This is why you see certain networks missing from my above example and why the second row isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$networks = $row['networks'];` Use this:

```
$a = json_decode($row['networks'], true);
$b = array_filter($a, function($el) {
  if ($el['detected'] == true) {
    return true;
  }
});
$c = implode(', ', array_keys($b));
$networks = $c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting the values into database do some checks on values of $netwrok. only when values are validated then insert

```
    foreach ($data as $row) {
$url = $row['url'];
$identifier = $row['identifier'];
$current_date = $row['current_date'];
$results = $row['results'];
$networks = $row['networks'];
//**insert you checks here ***//
    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $url = $row['url'];
    $identifier = $row['identifier'];
    $current_date = $row['current_date'];
    $results = $row['results'];
    $network_row = $row['networks'];

    $networks = '';

    foreach($network_row as $key => $val) {
        if ($val->detected == true) {
            $networks .= $key . ',';
        }
    }

    if (mb_strlen($networks, 'utf-8') > 0) {
        $networks = substr($networks, 0, mb_strlen($networks, 'utf-8')-1);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, but I'm getting `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 27`.  This is line 27:  `if ($val->detected == "true") {`.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the implode() function as part of the insert.
You can then use the explode() function when retrieving.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php